When i try to run model.fit() i face this error. how do i solve it
I am triying to follow a video and practice a lipnet Deep Learning Model that can LIP READ.
The code i am trying to run

Data Pipeline

data = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('./data/s1/*.mpg')
data = data.shuffle(500, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)
data = data.map(mappable_function)
data = data.padded_batch(2, padded_shapes=([75,None,None,None],[40]))
data = data.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
# Added for split
train = data.take(450)
test = data.skip(450)


Other model details

def scheduler(epoch, lr):
    if epoch < 30:
        return lr
    else:
        return lr * tf.math.exp(-0.1)

def CTCLoss(y_true, y_pred):
    batch_len = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[0], dtype="int64")
    input_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_pred)[1], dtype="int64")
    label_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[1], dtype="int64")

    input_length = input_length * tf.ones(shape=(batch_len, 1), dtype="int64")
    label_length = label_length * tf.ones(shape=(batch_len, 1), dtype="int64")

    loss = tf.keras.backend.ctc_batch_cost(y_true, y_pred, input_length, label_length)
    return loss

class ProduceExample(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback): 
    def __init__(self, dataset) -> None: 
        self.dataset = dataset.as_numpy_iterator()
    
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None) -> None:
        data = self.dataset.next()
        yhat = self.model.predict(data[0])
        decoded = tf.keras.backend.ctc_decode(yhat, [75,75], greedy=False)[0][0].numpy()
        for x in range(len(yhat)):           
            print('Original:', tf.strings.reduce_join(num_to_char(data[1][x])).numpy().decode('utf-8'))
            print('Prediction:', tf.strings.reduce_join(num_to_char(decoded[x])).numpy().decode('utf-8'))
            print('~'*100)

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), loss=CTCLoss)
checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(os.path.join('checkpoint.weights.h5'),monitor = 'loss', save_weights_only = True)
schedule_callback = LearningRateScheduler(scheduler)
example_callback = ProduceExample(test)

model.fit(data, validation_data = test, epochs=100, callbacks=[checkpoint_callback, schedule_callback, example_callback])

the error i am getting,
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[57], line 1
----> 1 model.fit(data, validation_data = test, epochs=100)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py:122, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    119     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    120     # To get the full stack trace, call:
    121     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 122     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    123 finally:
    124     del filtered_tb

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py:53, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     51 try:
     52   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 53   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     54                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     55 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     56   if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node sequential_1_1/time_distributed_1_1/Reshape_69 defined at (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 17, in <module>

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 1043, in launch_instance

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 701, in start

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 195, in start

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 603, in run_forever

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1909, in _run_once

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 534, in dispatch_queue

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 523, in process_one

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 429, in dispatch_shell

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 767, in execute_request

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 429, in do_execute

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 549, in run_cell

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3051, in run_cell

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3106, in _run_cell

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 129, in _pseudo_sync_runner

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3311, in run_cell_async

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3493, in run_ast_nodes

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3553, in run_code

  File "/tmp/ipykernel_34/125966584.py", line 1, in <module>

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 117, in error_handler

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py", line 314, in fit

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py", line 117, in one_step_on_iterator

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py", line 104, in one_step_on_data

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py", line 51, in train_step

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 117, in error_handler

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/layers/layer.py", line 846, in __call__

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 117, in error_handler

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/ops/operation.py", line 48, in __call__

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 156, in error_handler

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/models/sequential.py", line 209, in call

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/models/functional.py", line 202, in call

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/ops/function.py", line 155, in _run_through_graph

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/models/functional.py", line 592, in call

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 117, in error_handler

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/layers/layer.py", line 846, in __call__

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 117, in error_handler

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/ops/operation.py", line 48, in __call__

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 156, in error_handler

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/layers/rnn/time_distributed.py", line 108, in call

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/layers/rnn/time_distributed.py", line 108, in <listcomp>

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/layers/rnn/time_distributed.py", line 102, in step_function

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/layers/reshaping/flatten.py", line 54, in call

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/ops/numpy.py", line 4415, in reshape

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/numpy.py", line 1778, in reshape

Detected at node sequential_1_1/time_distributed_1_1/Reshape_69 defined at (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 17, in <module>

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 1043, in launch_instance

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 701, in start

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 195, in start

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 603, in run_forever

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1909, in _run_once

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 534, in dispatch_queue

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 523, in process_one

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 429, in dispatch_shell

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 767, in execute_request

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 429, in do_execute

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 549, in run_cell

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3051, in run_cell

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3106, in _run_cell

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 129, in _pseudo_sync_runner

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3311, in run_cell_async

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3493, in run_ast_nodes

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3553, in run_code

  File "/tmp/ipykernel_34/125966584.py", line 1, in <module>

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 117, in error_handler

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py", line 314, in fit

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py", line 117, in one_step_on_iterator

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py", line 104, in one_step_on_data

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py", line 51, in train_step

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 117, in error_handler

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/layers/layer.py", line 846, in __call__

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 117, in error_handler

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/ops/operation.py", line 48, in __call__

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 156, in error_handler

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/models/sequential.py", line 209, in call

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/models/functional.py", line 202, in call

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/ops/function.py", line 155, in _run_through_graph

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/models/functional.py", line 592, in call

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 117, in error_handler

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/layers/layer.py", line 846, in __call__

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 117, in error_handler

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/ops/operation.py", line 48, in __call__

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 156, in error_handler

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/layers/rnn/time_distributed.py", line 108, in call

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/layers/rnn/time_distributed.py", line 108, in <listcomp>

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/layers/rnn/time_distributed.py", line 102, in step_function

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/layers/reshaping/flatten.py", line 54, in call

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/ops/numpy.py", line 4415, in reshape

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/numpy.py", line 1778, in reshape

2 root error(s) found.
  (0) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  Only one input size may be -1, not both 0 and 1
     [[{{node sequential_1_1/time_distributed_1_1/Reshape_69}}]]
     [[StatefulPartitionedCall/compile_loss/ctc_loss/Log/_72]]
  (1) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  Only one input size may be -1, not both 0 and 1
     [[{{node sequential_1_1/time_distributed_1_1/Reshape_69}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_one_step_on_iterator_28512]

i dont quite understand the error, is there something wrong with the shape of the data i am trying to pass?? is that what that error means?
I have tried searching google about the InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error: but found no luck. Tried to run the code in cpu, gpu and tpu. Never worked with LSTM models before, is there any model layer errors?

Hello Rahat, the issue is not only with the data, but also with the model. Could you please share model code. Very much appreciate thanks.

I have edited my post and added cells that I thought were relevant. please let me know if I should add anything else. Thank you for looking into my problem.

You need to add model variable declaration as well because it is difficult to help you without knowing what your model looks like.
